# Magento2 Product add form custom form values not posting in observer

Tags: event-observer, template, magento2.2.2, tabs

I am Creating custom product add form in **magento2.2.2**.
I have added a new tab after **product details** & Loaded My custom phtml File into It,

First To Post Data from product form to observer, i added `data-form-part="product_form"` To input Fields Like:-

```
< input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" data-form-part="product_form" value="oldValue" / >
```

**Now**, When I click on **save** I called a event Like Below.

```
$(document).on('click','button[title="Save"], button[title="Duplicate"],  button[title="Save and Continue Edit"]',function(){
        $("#test").val('NewValue'); //Here I Changed Value According To My Requirement
});
```

In **MyObserver.php** For getting that hidden field value i used `$this->_request->getPost();`

By Printing Post Data of Test Hdden Input i got **OldValue** Instead of **NewValue** which is changed in jquery handler.

Any Solutions?